# Guild member add

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Been trying to log into me console when a new person join a a new server my console reports the guild name and amount members but it doesnt seem to work the error I get is that guild is not defined.

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => ch.name === "greetings");
  if (!channel) return;

  {
    var number = 31;
  }
  const image = Math.floor(Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  var rand = [
    "Some retard just joined",
    "This looser just made it",
    "This cringe person just joined",
    "LMAO look who joined",
    "Incoming Pleb!!",
    "Another Degenerate",
    "Another Basement Dweller",
    "Welcome you Wanker!!!",
  ];
  var choosen = rand[Math.floor(Math.random() * rand.length)];

  const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const background = await Canvas.loadImage(`./welcome/` + image + ".png");
  ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.strokeStyle = "#74037b";
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.font = "35px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.fillText(`${choosen}`, canvas.width / 3, canvas.height / 3.5);

  ctx.font = (canvas, `${member.username}!`);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.fillText(`${member.displayName}!`, canvas.width / 2.9, canvas.height / 1.8);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.clip();

  const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "jpg" }));
  ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

  const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), "welcome-image.png");

  channel.send(attachment);
  console.log(`${member} was added to ${guild.name}\n Server now has:${guild.memberCount}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you declared `guild` as a global variable outside of the scope of `client.on(...)`, it is indeed not defined. Probably what you want is `member.guild.name` and `member.guild.memberCount`